# Disable part of a QSlider

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qslider

I am looking for a way to disable a part of a [`QSlider`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qslider.html), and I mean disable it such that when you drag it it doesn't allow you to go passed a certain value. I know this effect is usually enforced with [`setMinumum()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#minimum-prop) and `setMaximum()`, but for UI reasons I want to set the range larger than the actual possible values set by the user.

In other words, I have  a set of sliders, which range is normalized [-2,2]. However I want to enforce one of this sliders only to be [-1,1], but for a better visualization I want such slider to have the same physical size as the others, but only let the user move between [-1,1]

Is there such a possibility?

Comment: Can you not restrict that on `mouseMoveEvent`?

Comment: @Azeem could you elaborate? I don't see what Event I could restrict with mouseMoveEvent such that it doesn't allow certain Slider positions. Are you thinking on restricting the positions the mouse can move?

Comment: You've read my mind. :) Yes. Exactly. That's is what I'm thinking.

Comment: @Azeem Seems overcomplicated to be. I think it should be possible to disable parts of the slider somehow...

Comment: Yes. But, I don't see anything relevant in the documentation. BTW, `sliderMoved` may also be used instead of the event and the slider position will also be in it.

Comment: I subclassed `QSlider` and re-implemented the [`sliderChange`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#sliderChange) method to *correct* the new value of the slider (to make it fit into the user-specified range). It seems to be working, You can have a look [here](https://pastebin.com/JpycY58D). It is in c++ as I don't have pyqt installed, but the concept should be the same in python.

Comment: but I had to use a *hack* to block signals from the object. That's why I think a cleaner way would be re-implementing `mouseMoveEvent` and filter the event at that level to make the slider only work on a specific range. . .

Comment: You can try to connect to `valueChanged` and clip the value when necessary.